# 504 Gateway Time-out Prestashop

Tags: php, nginx, prestashop

Вообщем есть VPS на котором развернута связка php 5.4 + mysql + nginx.
Используется движок Prestashop 1.6.1.4.
При импорте товаров и категорий из CSV файла, примерно через 30 секунд возникает ошибка "504 Gateway Time-out".
Я так понимаю, что проблема в том, что скрипт перестает выполняться по таймауту.
Куда копать и как правильно решить проблему?

В файлах  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini и cat /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 3600
```

В файле /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
worker_cpu_affinity 0101 1010;
timer_resolution 100ms;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
worker_priority -10;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 2048;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##



    reset_timedout_connection on;
    client_header_timeout 3600 ;
    client_body_timeout 3600;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
    proxy_send_timeout 3600;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    send_timeout 3600;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если больше кол-во товаров, то возможно время обработки скрипта не хватает

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка именно в скрипте/коде. Если бы ошибка появлялась постоянно, то был бы смысл проверять настройки сервера. А тут 100% ошибка в вашем коде.

P.S. Вчера у меня такая же была. Просто был вечный цикл...

Comment: В коде вряд ли есть ошибка так как во первых код не мой, а Prestashop'a,  а во вторых он отрабатывал на другом VPS сервере настроек которого к сожалению больше не удастся посмотреть.

Comment: Ну если вы ТОЧНО ничего не правили в коде и просто "установили из коробки", возможно существует потребность в увеличении технических возможностей сервера. Так же будет не плохо посмотреть логи.